# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(public/user_/,public/user_/)

Tags: php, recursiveiterator

I am getting this error while using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message
>   'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(public/user_/,public/user_/):
>   The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)' in
>   D:\xam\htdocs\s\upload.php:101 Stack trace: #0
>   D:\xam\htdocs\s\upload.php(101):
>   RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('public/user_/') #1
>   D:\xam\htdocs\s\upload.php(138): dirSize('public/user_/') #2 {main}
>   thrown in D:\xam\htdocs\s\upload.php on line 101

Here is the code i am using.

```
function dirSize($directory) {
    $size = 0;
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $file) {
        $size+=$file->getSize();
    }
    return $size;
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Please read how to ask the question (Format the code and description)

Comment: You could use a `try/catch` block and handle the error(s) in question.

Comment: @Paul Crovella Yeah . But how do i solve this ? Sorry I am a newbie

Answer (score -1):

There is a limited context here to see what is going wrong. However it would appear that your giving a directory to `D:\xam\htdocs\s\upload.php` that is not valid to start the iteration and find the size.

The `try/catch` option would stop it from throwing an error and failing

```
function dirSize($directory) {
  $size = 0;
  try {
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory)) as $file) {
      $size += $file->getSize();
    }
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e;
    echo "On: " . $directory;
  }
  return $size;
}
```